# KDE 5 / Plasma: Why does the fcitx / virtual keyboard display itself twice in the taskbar?

Tags: plasma5, fcitx

After fiddling around with the keyboard settings of my OpenSuSE Leap 15.3 machine, I've ended up with the `fcitx` and virtual keyboard applets appearing twice in the taskbar:

[image: taskbar]

Killing one applet also makes the second one disappear, and I can't find a menu entry allowing me to remove the superfluous applet. The applet selector also tells me that the applet in question has been loaded twice:

[image: applet selector]

So: What shall I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

1. Right-click on top dock - Edit dock
2. Right-click on any one of double widgets - Remove widget
3. Profit!

Comment: Yep, that was the (well-hidden) I was looking for. Thank you!